# Spring-Boot application does not build properly

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-tool-suite

my problem is when I trying to run my spring-boot project via STS or simple JavaApplication the changes after the last maven build are not built.

I'm tried several methods but, if I don't use maven build the project changes are not rebuilt.

Do you have any tips, what's wrong?

In the Project menu Build Automatically is selected. And the main method is annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`

(The hot-swap is not working too for me.)

[image]

Comment: Are you able to run `mvn clean compile` from command line? Sometimes the target folder is locked, causing similar problems...

Comment: Yes I can, the maven build works perfectly.

Comment: I used to use `mvn eclipse:eclipse` with Eclipse, give it a try ;-)

Comment: The problem is still here. I'm tried to add a console print in the main method, and simply ignored by Java application run. All build processes are ignored when I ain't use the maven.

Comment: And you are running application in debug mode, right? What Eclipse are you using? I meant, latest STS?

Comment: There is no difference in debug or normal mode. I use Eclipse Jee 2019-09 and the latest STS.

Comment: Idea is not doing hot swap during run, only during debug (I do not recall what Eclipse used to do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. In the `.project` file for my project I simply added a `javabuilder` build command. After that STS works perfectly and rebuilds the project before start. I think this problem occurs because I created a maven project, instead of creating a java project and convert it to a maven project.

[image]

Comment: But that's what `mvn eclipse:eclipse` should do... Can you remove `.project` (maybe `.classpath`) and execute `mvn eclipse:eclipse` to see if it was generated properly? Please add `.project` content as text, not as picture, thanks!

Comment: When I run ```mvn eclipse:eclipse```  did not do this. (Maybe because Eclipse are running). When I removed .proect and execute ```mvn eclipse:eclipse```  only the java build nature was added. 


```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
  <name>demo</name>
  <comment>Demo project for Spring Boot. NO_M2ECLIPSE_SUPPORT: Project files created with the maven-eclipse-plugin are not supported in M2Eclipse.</comment>
  <projects/>
  <buildSpec>
    <buildCommand>
      <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
    </buildCommand>
  </buildSpec>```

Answer (score 2):

I think . do clean first then right click project Maven-> update Maven. do clean again. plz

Comment: I'm tried it, nothing change, the maven build perfectly, but any changes after the maven build is ignored when I'm trying to run with other methods.

Comment: It looks like, when I use something different from Maven, the build process is not triggered. After the mvn clean, the STS can't find the main method.

Comment: can you delete .m2 folder and try Maven -> update maven ? but be careful , everyting is in .m2 folder

Answer (score 0):

If your project is gradle then go to Project right click and go to >gradle >Refresh gradle project.

Try to click ctrl +shift+O for import realated dependencies in your project.